# Receiving Push-Notifications from azure notification hub with ionic app

Tags: typescript, firebase, push-notification, ionic3, azure-notificationhub

I try to receive push-notfications from a correct configured notification hub at ANH but have still problems with registering the device. I get only the message 'waiting on registration ...' by using this example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Ionic/ionic-3

```
reinstalled the cordova plugin 

https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/Ionic/ionic-3

Error Message "waiting for registration ...". No device where registerd on the ANH!
```

Comment: Check this ttps://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/issues/83

Comment: Thank you, I will check it!